Is it possible to mount multiple items from different secrets to the same directory in K8s?
I have an app that requires three configuration files to be placed in the same directory. However the three configuration files come from two secrets and a config map.
All attempts so far have either resulted in an error from K8s because the different volumes have the same mountPath (different subPath), or have resulted in directories in the file path I wanted a file.
The ideal result would be a container with:
/app/config/database.json        <-- File from secret 1
/app/config/message_broker.json  <-- File from secret 2
/app/config/app_config.json      <-- File from config map

Is this possible, or is it just a limitation of K8s?

As per this official kubernetes document on Projected Volumes :

A projected volume maps several existing volume sources into the same directory.
You can use a single volume and strategically use subPaths within that volume.
Currently, the following types of volume sources can be projected:

secret

downwardAPI

configMap

serviceAccountToken

clusterTrustBundle


All sources are required to be in the same namespace as the Pod. For more details, see the all-in-one volume design document.

Example configuration with a secret, a downwardAPI, and a configMap :
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: volume-test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: container-test
    image: busybox:1.28
    command: ["sleep", "3600"]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: all-in-one
      mountPath: "/projected-volume"
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: all-in-one
    projected:
      sources:
      - secret:
          name: mysecret
          items:
            - key: username
              path: my-group/my-username
      - downwardAPI:
          items:
            - path: "labels"
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.labels
            - path: "cpu_limit"
              resourceFieldRef:
                containerName: container-test
                resource: limits.cpu
      - configMap:
          name: myconfigmap
          items:
            - key: config
              path: my-group/my-config

Also refer to this how to Configure a Pod to Use a Projected Volume for Storage for more information.
